# PHP fill array into for

Tags: php

in this below code i want to fill array with for repeator. `echo` can display and not have problem but. my array could not fill by `for`.

```
<meta charset='UTF-8' />
<?php
error_reporting(1);
$handle='A-file.txt';
$handle = file_get_contents($handle);
$lines = explode(PHP_EOL,$handle );
$names = array();
for( $i = 0; count($lines)-1 ; $i+=4 )
{
    $names[]= $lines[$i];

    //$names= $lines[$i];
    //$names[]+= $lines[$i];
    //echo $lines[$i];
}
print_r($names);
?>
```

Comment: `for( $i = 0; $i <= count($lines)-1 ; $i+=4 )`

Comment: `$i<count($lines)-1;`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You've forgotten the comparison with `$i`:

```
for( $i = 0; $i <= count($lines)-1 ; $i+=4 )
{
    $names[]= $lines[$i];

    //$names= $lines[$i];
    //$names[]+= $lines[$i];
    //echo $lines[$i];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this, You have missed to add `$i < count($lines)-1`

```
for( $i = 0; $i < count($lines)-1; $i+=4 )
```

instead of

```
for( $i = 0; count($lines)-1 ; $i+=4 )
```

Answer (score 1):

Check the file has more than 4 lines, and the for finishes with that condition maybe will be an eternal loop.

Answer (score 0):

This is perhaps just a tip to solve the problem more likely.

Use file() (http://php.net/file) to directly read a file's content into an array (so you don't need to do it manually with more lines then needed) and iterate over these lines using foreach($lines as $i => $line) {...} instead. To skip lines you can do:

if($i % $nthElem !== 0) continue;

You could even do it in one turn:

```
foreach(file($yourFile) as $i => $line){
   if($i % 4 !== 0) continue;
```

Answer (score -1):

Always optimize your for loop by putting count function out of for loop and store it in a variable. Use that in the loop

```
$count = count($lines);
for( $i = 0; $count-1 ; $i+=4 ) {

}
```